# Shared RadioButton Component in Angular2

Tags: angular, data-binding, radio-button, components, shared

I want to reuse my component at the same page, but I have the problem to define the value of my Radio Buttons depending the one I am working on.

I have three shared-components and I don't know how to do it to difference them. I mean, if I work on the first, I don't want the other 2 components get modified. 
I solved using a "drastic" mode, and I would like to do it better. Any Suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="ui form">
  <div class="inline fields">
    <label for="fruit">Send to:</label>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="radio{{A}}{{B}}" value="selected" [(ngModel)]="option">
        <label>Send Selected</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="radio{{A}}{{B}}" value="all" [(ngModel)]="option">
        <label>Send All</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The way I'm doing is to declare the value A and B, which are booleans, but I think is a bad way to resolve it.

The variables from his components are:

```
@Input() A: boolean;
@Input() B: boolean;
@Input() C: boolean;
private option: string = 'selected';
```

Is there any method to improve this solution? :

```
name="radio{{A}}{{B}}"
```

Comment: have you defined input for your component? if you share your component and want to make difference when you use your shared component, you need define some input to make this different. Such as you want different name of component, you need define input for name, and bind the input to the view.

Comment: I don't understand you, because I have one unique component which is shared 3 times, so I can not define an "id" to them. I made the input to the variables booleans.

Comment: could you show your code of the unique component and the usage of your component?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what purpose A, B and C serve, but using only 2 booleans would severely limit the amount of unique possible instances you could use.

Regardless, I would do one of the following:

- Create a service to generate unique `name`s for each instance of the component which the component will call upon `OnInit`, and store for the rest of its lifetime (which of course you could recycle `OnDestroy`).
- Add another `@Input` for the radio group's name and let the component's consumer decide how to name the group.

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed you don't have to use the `name=` attribute, you can omit it, angular automatically groups radio inputs when they are bound using `[(ngModel)]` to the same "thing".

Comment: i think the poster is running into the issue of radio button groups from different shared components sharing the same state if they have the same name.  How does omitting the name prevent this from happening?

Comment: I just tested it and it does not. The only solution (as far as I know) is to generated unique name for grouped buttons